# How to backup Zsh customization?

Tags: linux, zsh

So, I've transitioned from using `bash` to using `zsh`. And I found the awesome repository known as ***oh-my-zsh*** and used that to base my own `zsh` customizations.

Now, I want to backup my configuration/customization not just as a backup if I ever have to restore my system, but also to apply to new installations.

I plan on tarball-ing the following files/directories:

- `~/.oh-my-zsh/`
- `~/.zshrc`
- `~/.zshrc.zni`

Will these be enough?

Comment: Only you know if you have made any other customisation changes ...

Comment: @DavidPostill in general, I'm not looking forward to answering all those questions Zsh asks on first-time use 

Comment: @pepoluan These questions are only asked, if there is no `~/.zshrc`. And usually *Oh-My-Zsh* overrides much of these settings anyway, if it does not outright replace `~/.zshrc` with its own version on installation.

Comment: @Adaephon understood. but I _do_ customized Zsh a bit though all those questions. I'm just not looking forward to reanswer the questions _again_ every time.